# bpy.ops.uv.project_from_view get an error

Tags: python

[image]

Hi,
I'm trying make script for 'project from view' in 'UV Unwrap Face'.
Below is my code :

import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="FACE")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action= 'SELECT')
bpy.ops.uv.project_from_view()

It seems that the last line is not working.
How can I solve it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is you are receiving  an incorrect context error. The operator needs to be run in the context of the 3d view  (eg When it is invoked from menu in 3d view), not the text editor.  Probable duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99035/how-to-unwrap-project-from-view-with-script  related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185496/how-to-unwrap-a-mesh-from-view-in-python-blender-2-8

Comment: Thank you @batFINGER